# Why doesn't the changes on a shallow copy of a vtk object in C++ affect the original object

Tags: c++, vtk

I have the following c++ code:

```
vtkNew _surf;
_surf->ShallowCopy(surf);
vtkIdType cellId = Get_ClosestCellId(_surf, seedxyz);
_surf->DeleteCell(cellId);
_surf->RemoveDeletedCells();
```

After creating `_surf`, we specify it as a `ShallowCopy` of `surf` then remove the cell closest to the `seedxyz` by calling `_surf->DeleteCell`

I thought that if I `ShallowCopy` like this, since `_surf` and `surf` share the same pointer, the modifications made to `_surf` would also be reflected in `surf`.

However, if you output the two in vtp format, `_surf` is modified but `surf` does not show the changes. Why is this?

Comment: What I meant by “translation” is the translation of language. I am not from an English-speaking country. Sorry for confusing you.

I shallow copied structure a into b. Afterwards, modifications were made to the a structure. In that case, I think the modification of a should be applied to b, but it did not proceed that way.

  Can you elaborate on the part about "apply"? When _surf was exported, the modifications had already been applied.

Comment: Ha! Yes I see the confusion, translation works for both language and geometry. I updated your question, I think it makes sense. Can you check to see if it is still what you're asking?

Comment: What is the object `surf`.

Comment: What you're thinking is correct! Thanks for the help. surf is surface data imported in vtkPolyData format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made this very simple example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A{
public:
    float* pos;
    void ShallowCopy(A* other){
        other->pos = pos;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** args){
    A* surf = new A();
    float* pos = new float[1];
    pos[0] = 5;
    surf->pos = pos;
    A* b = new A();
    surf->ShallowCopy(b);

    printf(" startt: %f\n", surf->pos[0]);

    b->pos[0] = 10;

    printf(" first: %f\n", surf->pos[0]);

    float* other = new float[1];
    other[0] = 20;
    b->pos = other;
    printf(" after: %f\n", surf->pos[0]);
    delete surf, b;
    delete[] other, pos;
}
```

The output is:

> startt: 5.000000
> first: 10.000000
> after: 10.000000

The idea is that the shallow copy uses the the same backing data, `pos`, so changes in `pos` are reflected in both copies. Both objects have their own pointer to `pos` so when you `b->pos =  other` it isn't reflected in `surf`

Since the object `surf` is a vtkPolyData we can hunt down the ShallowCopy docs [vtkObject ShallowCopy](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataObject.html#a04a5fb60bdbc929ce84f0cd14d911dbe).

> The goal of the method is to copy the data up to the array pointers only.

Both vtkObjects have a list of CellId's, adding or removing cell id's will not be reflected in the other class. Changing the cells themselves would be reflected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I know my depth of learning was “shallow.” Thanks to you, my curiosity was resolved. Thank you so much again!!

Comment: You should probably add the missing `delete` / `delete[]`. Currently, this snippet leaks.

Comment: The above part is declared in a function of the vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> format, so I think the memory will be automatically released as soon as the function ends.

Comment: @Erel I updated the shallow copy. Of course this is just to illustrate the concept of a shallow copy. I expect pos shouldn't be a float* but some sort of managed pointer as OP has said that VTK is using.

Comment: It's easier for me to understand. Thank you for your great help!